# Babel does not polyfill Web Worker importScript

Tags: babeljs, web-worker, babel-polyfill

I have a simple Web Worker based project, transpiled with `babel`, where I have in my `worker.js`

```
importScripts('webGLWorker.js');
importScripts('proxyWorker.js');
```

while in my `index.js` I have

```
<script src="webGLClient.js"></script>
<script src="proxyClient.js"></script>
```

My `babel` config is (`.babelrc`)

```
{
  "presets": [
    [
      "env",
      {
        "esmodules": false,
        "targets": {
          "browsers": [
            "> 3%"
          ]
        }
      }
    ]
  ],
  "plugins": [
    "transform-runtime"
  ]
}
```

When I run, the files imported by `importScripts` are not found (404), since `babel` is ignoring them basically, so I will not find them in my `dist/` project folder among the other files (`index.html`, other js, etc.).

Specifically I'm using `parcel`, here is how the interesting part of my `package.json` looks like:

```
{
"scripts": {
    "watch": "cross-env NODE_ENV=development parcel index.html --no-hmr --open",
    "build": "cross-env NODE_ENV=production parcel build index.html --no-minify --public-url ./"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "babel-plugin-transform-runtime": "~6.23.0",
    "babel-polyfill": "~6.26.0",
    "babel-preset-env": "~1.6.1",
    "clang-format": "~1.2.2",
    "cross-env": "^5.1.6",
    "parcel-bundler": "~1.8.1"
  }
}
```